# How to move Eclipse project from one Github repo to another?

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

I am new to github. I cloned my github repo to eclipse using EGit.
Now, I have two repo in my Eclipse.
I added my Java Eclipse project to the old repo. I would like to added my Java Eclipse project to new repo. How could I move my Eclipse project from one repo to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From eclipse, you can right click on a project and select the Team > Disconnect menu option to disassociate the project with the old git repository. Then right click the project again and select the Team > Share Project option.  From the 'Configure Git Repository' dialog, you may need to uncheck the "Use or create repository in parent folder of project" check box.  You will then be able to select the location of the git repository you want to associate with the project.